# gcc optimization impact on shared library operation

Tags: c, gcc, shared-libraries, message-queue, fpic

I have an own shared library, compiled and linked as below:

```
gcc -g -Wall -fpic -c -o cont.o cont.c
gcc -g -shared -o libcont.so cont.o -lrt
```

I have a program (`nr`) which uses this library:

```
gcc -g -Wall -I/include_path -c -o nr.o nr.c
gcc -L/shared_lib_path nr.o -lcont -o nr
```

One of the shared library's functions, if invoked, calls POSIX message sending (`mq_send()`) possibly which results an assertion error. `strace ./nr` says the following about this:

```
) = 1 (in [5])
mq_timedreceive(5, "\17\0ryName\0stester\0\t\0op\0srate\0\22\0ro"..., 2000, 0, NULL) = 76
mq_open("tester_asdf", O_WRONLY|O_NONBLOCK) = 6
writev(2, [{"Inconsistency detected by ld.so:"..., 33}, {"dl-lookup.c", 11}, {": ", 2}, {"167", 3}, {": ", 2}, {"check_match", 11}, {": ", 2}, {"Assertion `", 11}, {"version->filename == ((void *)0)"..., 79}, {"' failed!\n", 10}], 10Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-lookup.c: 167: check_match: Assertion `version->filename == ((void *)0) || ! _dl_name_match_p (version->filename, map)' failed!
) = 164
```

The very interesting thing is, that if I compile the program with any level of optimization other than the default (e.g., `-O3`), everything works fine:

```
gcc -g -Wall -O3 -I/include_path -c -o nr.o nr.c
gcc -L/shared_lib_path nr.o -lcont -o nr
```

In this case `strace ./nr` says:

```
) = 1 (in [5])
mq_timedreceive(5, "\17\0ryName\0stester\0\t\0op\0srate\0\22\0ro"..., 2000, 0, NULL) = 76
mq_open("tester_asdf", O_WRONLY|O_NONBLOCK) = 6
mq_timedsend(6, "\t\0op\0srate\0\22\0root\0scall_rating\0\t"..., 59, 0, NULL) = 0
mq_timedreceive(5, "\t\0op\0srate\0\22\0root\0scall_rating\0\t"..., 2000, 0, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
pselect6(6, [5], NULL, NULL, NULL, {~[INT ILL BUS FPE KILL SEGV ALRM TERM STOP RTMIN], 8}
```

Which is exactly that I would expect independently from the optimization level.

What could be the possible reason causing this?

The corresponding **code** snippet:

```
fprintf(stderr, "mqFd: %d, msg: %p, size: %d\n", (int)mqFd, msg, (int)size);
mq_send(mqFd, msg, size, 0);
```

`fprintf` prints just before the `mq_send`:

```
mqFd: 6, msg: 0x7ffdadef1820, size: 59
```

which is fine, but calling `mq_send` results the above detailed assertion.

Comment: So stuff is getting optimized away. Which stuff? We can't tell without seeing your code. Which is likely to contain a UB.

Comment: The program could be writing beyond the bounds of an array, and optimization could be rearranging the layout of variables adjacent to that array.

Comment: I've just added the corresponding code to the question. Still in doubt. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think this part from gcc man page, might be relevant to what you see:

> ```
>    -shared
>        Produce a shared object which can then be linked with other objects to form an executable.
>        Not all systems support this option.  For predictable results, you must also specify the
>        same set of options used for compilation (-fpic, -fPIC, or model suboptions) when you
>        specify this linker option.[1]
> ```

This means, you need to add `-fpic` to the command line of the library creation.

Comment: As it can be seen in the very first code block, it was created with -fpic.

Comment: You didn't read what I wrote. I don't see this option in the lib creation command line as the man page suggests.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and sorry for answering this late. -shared is a linker option, while -fpic is a compiler one. The 1st line in the abovementioned block is for compiling and the 2nd one is for linking. The man page - as far as I understand - says, that distinct codes that link together must be compiled the very same way. In this case I have only one source to form the shared library.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What I really think in this snippet of man page is that, you should specify `-fPIC` that you used in the compilation also when you used `-shared` in building your shared library. Again, here is the critical part "For predictable results, you must also specify the same set of options used for compilation (-fpic, -fPIC, or model suboptions) when you specify this linker option." i.e. you are missing `-fPIC`, my 2 cents. Thanks!

Comment: You are right, know I finally see that this says that you say. Sorry for understanding this hard. Besides the problem was not this. I mistakenly copied some bytes to a wrong place, which did not result immediate crush but this strange behavior. After correcting that, the problem vanished. Thanks again.

Comment: Good to know you have fixed your issue.